# Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Suppose $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and that $x_0$ is in the domain of both functions and an accumulation point of their intersection. Suppose further that there exists $\mu >0$ such that the intersection of the $\mu$-neighborhood of $x_0$ with $D$ is equal to the intersection of the $\mu$-neighborhood with $E$ and for all $x$ in that intersection, $f(x)=g(x)$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$

---

The concept of this proof is not really clicking with me,Given most of my theorems and lemmas of differentiability state the use of one function,I'm lost on how to approach the proof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: write down the *definition* of $f'(x_0)$ and $g'(x_0)$.

---

Denote the "$\mu$-neighborhood" of $x_0$ as $H$. Then $S:=H\cap D=H\cap E$. Also $f=g$ on $S$.

Now 
$$
f'(x_0)=\lim_{\substack{x\to x_0\\x\in S\setminus\{x_0\}}}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}
=\lim_{\substack{x\to x_0\\x\in S\setminus\{x_0\}}}\frac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Just to further affirm, we denote $H$ as stated, therefore we can assume $S$ be the domain of the intersection, thus it follows that $f$ is differentiable iff $g$ is differentiable. I think I have it down. Thank you

Comment: @EverOlivares: You are welcome. More or less that. It is because $f$ and $g$ agree on the set $S$. Essentially, The derivative is a "local" concept and it depends only on the behavior of the function "near" the point where one wants to consider its derivative.